# how to convert *int64 to *int32?

Tags: go, pointers

I have a `*int64` as one of the parameters in my function, and I need to convert it to `*int32` to meet the definition of the function I want to call.

```
func t1(x *int64) error {
    var y *int32   
    t2(y)
}
func t2(y *int32) error {}
```

And, if I want to convert `*int32` to `*int8`, then do I need another function? Is there a way to handle such problems?

Comment: You are downscaling going from `int64` to `int32` so there may be data loss.

Answer (score 2):

> [H]ow to convert *int64 to *int32?

You cannot.

Use `var i32 int32 = int32(*x); t2(&i32); *x=int64(i32)`.

Comment: And because you're only able to handle i32 here - you'll need to put a check on your input to ensure that you don't experience data loss (that the primary input doesn't exceed 32 bits!) - otherwise your function is a going to return garbage.

Comment: and because you're doing this dangerous thing - you might need to walk back up the chain and decide to either do the whole thing in i64, or i32 - but not try to mix them, ever.  You're begging for a data overflow problem / garbage out.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Golang has generic types which can help you to have a generic converting function:

```
type IntNumber interface {
 int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64
}
func IntNumberPointersToPointers(T IntNumber, K IntNumber)(from *T) *K {
  if from == nil {
    return nil
  }
  result := K(*from)
  return &result
}
```

You can call the function by:

```
// The result will be int
input := int32(100)
result := util.IntNumberPointersToPointers[int32, int](&input)
```

Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/sRP17iFX6J6

Assume that you are aware about converting big int to smaller may cause data loss. E.g `int64` to `int32`